# Does Bash through Linux as a Subsystem for Win10 replace Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, command-line-interface, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm in the process of learning how to create Wordpress templates, and as a part of that was told to install Git, npm, node and gulp. However, the online course leaves out details about where stuff gets installed to through commands in CLI, what CLI to use (as now, after installing the stuff, I have several CLIs, or command prompts ...), and when to install stuff globally and when locally (and where exactly locally would be here). So in my search for answers, I found that the Windows command prompt (or terminal or CLI) would not understand all the needed commands (for reasons of them being unix lingo), and that therefore Git Bash should be used (duh?). However, now I read (in more recent articles, like this one [Discover the power of Bash on Windows](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3178631/microsoft-windows/discover-the-power-of-bash-on-windows.html) ) that using the unix command line Bash through Linux on Windows as a subsystem would be so wonderful that, it seems to me, it replaces the use of Git Bash?

If I'm not into using Git repositories yet and simply want to use the CLI that's most useful for my purposes, is enabling Linux as subsystem for Windows and using the resulting Bash the done thing now?

Or did I get the wrong idea somewhere along the line, and could use Windows's PowerShell just as well?

I'm not seeing the light here, and would great appreciate advice. Thx.

Comment: Last I tried bash on Windows did not include a lot of common Unix utilities that are required and assumed under Linux systems.  git bash is still much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with Linux or use linux most often you should run linux w/ a linux shell (bash, ksh, zsh, etc). If you run windows and work with windows, you should learn how to use Powershell.

Powershell is a very powerful tool for use on windows but if you are familiar with only linux commands and only need it for basic things like ls, ll, cat, grep, etc. it may suit your needs. Powershell can do more in Windows than Git Bash ever will.

Its sounds to me as if your instruction is being done via someone using Linux and you are on windows. Maybe switch to Unix as your primary operating system.